# Python - except (OSError, e) - No longer working in 3.3.3?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.3

The following have worked throughout Python 3.X and is not broke in 3.3.3, can't find what's changed in the docs.

```
import os

def pid_alive(pid):
    pid = int(pid)
    if pid < 0:
        return False
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except (OSError, e):
        return e.errno == errno.EPERM
    else:
        return True
```

Tried different variations of the except line, for instance `except OSError as e:` but then `errno.EPERM` breaks etc.

Any quick pointers?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The expression `except (OSError, e)` *never* worked in Python, not in the way you think it works. That expresion catches *two* types of exception; `OSError` or whatever the global `e` refers to. Your code breaks when there is no global name `e`.

The correct expression for Python 3 and Python 2.6 and newer is:

```
except OSError as e:
```

Python 2 also supports the syntax:

```
except OSError, e:
```

without parenthesis, or:

```
except (OSError, ValueError), e:
```

to catch more than one type. The syntax was very confusing, as you yourself discovered here.

The change was added in Python 2.6 and up, see [PEP 3110 - Catching Exceptions in Python 3000](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110) and the [Exception-handling changes section](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes) of the 2.6 What's New document.

As for an exception for `errno.EPERM`; you didn't import `errno`, so that is a `NameError` as well.

Comment: Missed `import errno` as well, that was the root cause and again a stupid question on my part which i spent a few hours on.. What's the difference between `(OSError, e)` and `X as Y`? Edit: Thanks for clairifying the syntax of it!

Comment: @Torxed: `except X, Y` (*without* parenthesis) was replaced by `except X as Y`, because it was too close to `except (X, Y)`, which means 'catch one of these *two* types'.

Comment: Yea I see it/understand it now, simple answer once you get it in front of you which makes the question rather silly. Sorry to bother you and thank you for the answer, opened my eyes a bit :)

Comment: Thank you! It's 2018 and Dropbox has still not cared to fix that!

Comment: @ToniAz I’m not sure what you mean. What should Dropbox fix?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, excuse me. This python script from Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py is rife with these "Errors"!

Comment: @ToniAz that file uses the valid Python 2 syntax, no parentheses. So the code will work correctly under older Python 2 releases, including Python 2.5. That’s probably deliberate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters typed python2 dropbox.py and it worked like a charm! Thanks! Didn't expect help with this.